# Maximum weight of an edge in a cycle in graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I am trying to modify the minimum spanning tree if the weight of an edge in the graph not belonging to MST is decreased.I read on stackoverflow that first connect the edge to the MST
now there is exactly one cycle in MST and by cycle property the edge whose weight is maximum in cycle can be deleted from MST? How to find the max weight edge in that cycle?

Comment: Do you need to do this only once ?

Comment: i have to decrease the weight of an edge only once..

Comment: Which algorithm have u used for finding MST. Also which data structure have you used. I need to know this since if you have used   union-find datastructure then i think i have a better solution

Comment: i havent implemented it yet but i will use kruskal and union find data structure.

Comment: Ok once u have the MST saved in the union find data structure. Suppose the edge connecting node I and J has it's weight decreased. Now start with node I move towards root of the MST and check if an edge has weight greater than weight of node(I,J). if yes then u are done. Otherwise do the same for Node J. I think it's a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the new edge added be between node **i** and **j**.There will be exactly one cycle containing all nodes between node **i** and **j**, including them. Also as before it was a tree only one path is there from node **i** to **j**. So you can use DFS/BFS to traverse the graph and calculate the maximum weight of any edge occurring in the path from  **i** to **j**.If the maximum weight is less than that of new edge weight, don't add the new one.Else remove the previous one and add this one.The complexity would 
be **O(V)**.
Following is the pseudo code , here **ans[k][0],ans[k][1]** store the nodes such that the edge between these nodes is of maximum weight if the source node is **i** and destination **k** and **ans[k][2]** as weight of that edge.

```
   for all nodes
       mark them unvisited
       mark ans[node][2] as -1
   /*i is the node which is one of the nodes of two of the new edge (i--j) */
   Push node i in queue Q
   mark node i visited
   while Q is not empty
       assign current_node as front element of Q
       pop Q
       for all neighbors of current_node
           if neighbor is unvisited
               mark neighbor visited
               assign w to be maximum of weight of edge (current_node---neighbor) and ans[current_node]
               if w is greater than ans[neighbor]
                  ans[neighbor][2] = w
                  ##Depending on which was max in the the if condition
                  ans[neighbor][0] = current_node/ans[current_node][0]
                  ans[neighbor][1] = neighbor/ans[current_node][1]

               push neighbor in Q  
if weight of edge (i--j) is greater than ans[j][2] 
     don't add the new edge
else 
     remove edge (ans[j][0]---ans[j][1]) and add edge (i--j)
```

Comment: by using bfs i have to keep track of the parent of each vertices than only i can get the path from a vertex to another.am i correct?

Comment: i meant to say that do i need to backtrack once i reach vertex j from i using bfs to get maximum weight of edge in that path?

Comment: no you only need to know what was maximum edge uptill then